# cannot delete unknown replicaset

Tags: openshift

all:

I got the following error when trying to delete an unknow replicaset. I asked my team and nobody claimed the ownership of this rs so i decided to delete it. but got this error.

```
➜  ~ oc get rs
NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
argocd-applicationset-controller-5466d654d5   1         1         1       7d9h
argocd-redis-fc877b4d                         1         1         1       23d
argocd-repo-server-58964f65bd                 1         1         1       23d
argocd-server-58b688f5d8                      1         1         1       23d
gowebapi-796fdbf457                           3         0         0       11d
pgo-676cdd4459                                1         1         0       17h
postgresql-standalone-db-57d677f8ff           0         0         0       39m
postgresql-standalone-db-65f79d87             1         1         1       100m
➜  ~ oc delete rc pgo-676cdd4459
Error from server (NotFound): replicationcontrollers "pgo-676cdd4459" not found
➜  ~ oc get rs
NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
argocd-applicationset-controller-5466d654d5   1         1         1       7d9h
argocd-redis-fc877b4d                         1         1         1       23d
argocd-repo-server-58964f65bd                 1         1         1       23d
argocd-server-58b688f5d8                      1         1         1       23d
gowebapi-796fdbf457                           3         0         0       11d
pgo-676cdd4459                                1         1         0       17h
postgresql-standalone-db-57d677f8ff           0         0         0       39m
postgresql-standalone-db-65f79d87             1         1         1       100m
➜  ~
```

Besides, in the log file, it shows the following error:

```
W1012 19:04:38.174999 1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:dbaas-dev--runtime-int:pgo" cannot list resource "statefulsets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope
E1012 19:04:38.175049 1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.StatefulSet: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:dbaas-dev--runtime-int:pgo" cannot list resource "statefulsets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope
```

Comment: Please write the command you executed and what roles are you assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to delete a `replicationcontroller` (`rc`) and you are listing `replicasets` (`rs`).

So that's your immediate problem: just a one character typo in your delete command. If you did `oc delete rs pgo-676cdd4459` it would, assuming you have the right permissions, delete the replicaset.

That said:

- Why are you deleting and working with replicasets? Typically if you delete a replicaset it is just going to get immediately recreated by the deployment or whatever is its parent is.
- Most likely a pgo replicaset is your Postgres operator
- If you want more information on it (for example, what image it's running which would be a good hint as to what it is), I'd recommend doing a `describe` on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, @David Ogren, it was proved that this replicaset was created when the team installed the CrunchyData PGO operator, after i deleted it, the PGO stopped working. I had to reinstall the operator to make it functional again. Good listen to learn!